# upgrading from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I am new to magento. If I use the Package upgrade available through magento connect downloader do I need to backup and overwite my custom files as in the upgrade roadmap when upgrading a full magento installation?

For modules such as Lib_Magento, Lib_Mage & Lib_Unserialize ,,,etc. I am in version 1.9.2.3 would like to upgrade to 1.9.2.4.

If this is not the correct path please suggest the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.2.4. updates the following files from 1.9.2.3:

1. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
3. app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
4. lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Without knowing the exact files you mean by "custom files", if any of these files are overridden in the app/code/core or lib/ directory which is considered bad practice, you can copy these to app/code/local before upgrading.

e.g. "app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php" would be copied to "app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php".

See app/Mage.php and lib/Varien/Autoload.php files for how autoloading works in Magento.

You can also upgrade using shell providing you have shell access and you know how to use shell. I would also test this locally before applying on a live site.

You can download and apply the patch 7405 from [www.magento.com/download](http://www.magento.com/download) for 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4 by moving the patch file into your Magento root directory and then from the command line

1. cd path/to/magento_root
2. sh patch_file_name.sh

Then delete the the patch file name.

Comment: I forgot to say. Backup your site before running the patch just as a precautionary measure.

Answer (score 0):

If you done some changes in core files then you should follow below links.
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2014/03/03/override-magento-core-files-simplest-way/
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Afer that please Reindex and Refresh Cache.
And check your all functionality is working as per your requirement or not.

Then backup your All magento files and Database

Goto connect manager
click on Check for Upgrades 
Then you can see available updates for magento.
Then just click on Mage_All_Latest to newly available upgrade 
And it will update your all magento functionality 
Now some are remaining those are your third party extension you need to update them one by one.

No necessary for patches you have installed magento  1.9.2.4

[Is there any necessary for patches if i have installed Magento 1.9.2.4](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128060/is-there-any-necessary-for-patches-if-i-have-installed-magento-1-9-2-4/128064#128064)

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.4.html