# Is there any necessary for patches if i have installed Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches

Currently i have upgrade my Magento from 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4

So should i also need to install patches ?

I have followed these links

(https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.263831883.634541803.1469616061) for Patches there are 
patch: SUPEE-6237
patch: SUPEE-5344 
patch: SUPEE-1533
patch: SUPEE-4291/4334 these patches are available for 1.9.x but i have tried for patch but getting error.

```
dev]# sh PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 44.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 58.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 69.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.rej
```

So should i apply patches or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment.

Magento 1.9.2.4 is shipped with all the last patches.

You can see the list of patches included with the version in the official download page: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

> Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
>   SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1

Comment: Thank you for reply, But what about remaining patches as SUPEE-1533, SUPEE-4291/4334.

Comment: @SurajSakhare not required for Magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 2):

You can check for available patches using the command line as explained at https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9bc45ec84028611d621e

> 1. First you need to generate download token. Login to your account on magento.com and generate it in Account Settings->Downloads Access Token
> 2. You will need your MAGEID as well. It is shown at the top-left in your account page.
> 3. curl -k https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/help
> 4. Profit!

To check which patches are required for Magento 1.9.2.2, run

```
curl -k https://$MAGEID:$MAGETOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/filter/version/1.9.2.2
```

with $MAGEID and $MAGETOKEN being your id and token from above.
To download a file from the list, run

```
curl -O https://$MAGEID:$MAGETOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/file/$FILENAME
```

with $FILENAME being the patch file name.

---

As of now (2016/07/29) there are no patches for version 1.9.2.4. Magento got into the habit of releasing new patch releases for 1.9 when a patch was released, so that the latest version should always be good.

This is the current output of the first command from above

```
File Description                 File Type                         Md5 Hash                                  Publication Date             Version          File Name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
magento-1.9.2.4.zip              Community Edition - Full          ff27580af148c7084ff6e89cc46577c0          2016-02-23 09:58:00          1.9.2.4          magento-1.9.2.4.zip
magento-1.9.2.4.tar.gz           Community Edition - Full          0ee115245aea158b03d584dc6c1d5466          2016-02-23 10:02:00          1.9.2.4          magento-1.9.2.4.tar.gz
magento-1.9.2.4.tar.bz2          Community Edition - Full          2e0d45617e3940324311c534db8f69f0          2016-02-23 10:04:00          1.9.2.4          magento-1.9.2.4.tar.bz2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You see the only downloads related to 1.9.2.4 are the full releases, no additional patches.